# SSRS - Setting Table Row Height

Tags: reporting-services

I'm working in a SSRS report. I have a table in the report. How do I set the row height of the rows in the table?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Select the row you want to change the height of.  With that row selected bring up the properties pane (Alt+enter if you don't see it).  Scroll down to the position group of properties and specify the width and height there.  The "cangrow" and "canshrink" properties are useful too sometimes.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Scott. I'm not able to see any position group of properties in the properties pane.

Comment: Ditto on not finding any position properties. There is a "size" group with an expander but when you click it, it disappears. It doesn't appear to have a value, or allow you to set one. Is it possible this is something that SSRS 00' had that Scott refers to? As of right now there's no way to know from the designer how tall a row is. So when you have to adjust multiple next to each other you just have to sort of guess and adjust until it "looks right" which is not what I was going for.

Comment: Just select one header cell, then you should be able to change size of the row inside Position group. .

Comment: I also do not see a "position" field under properties.

Comment: This is not possible in Report Viewer ver. 12+. Too bad. Such a useful feature.

Comment: You have to select a **cell** in the row, not the row, then it works.

Comment: This only changed the row size in design view only.

Answer (score 8):

Select one cell in a row , go to properties, go to size, give width and height and dis-select "allow textbox height to increase" and "allow textbox height to decrease" in textbox properties. Then it will effect on whole row.

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the RDL(C) and set it exactly using an XML editor.

Look for the following:

```
...
          <TablixRows>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>1.5in</Height>
...
```

Note that you must have set the row height before there will be a Height node.

Answer (score 3):

Since a tablix row doesn't have a dynamic height property (only `CanGrow` and `CanShrink` properties), I came up with a workaround.

You can use the length function `LEN()` in the Value expression for a cell in the row you want more height and add whitespace to the bottom (or top) of the cell with `<br/>` tags, thus effectively changing the row height dynamically.

To do this, first in the Placeholder Properties of the cell, **change the markup type to "HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles"**. (Just like changing the *static* row height property for a cell, this will change the height for the entire row.)

The "dynamic" whitespace you add to the bottom (or top) of the cell depends on how many `<br/>` tags you append to the value. Here's an example to add whitespace to the row if the cell has a value length of 100 or more characters (increasing the whitespace for every additional 100 characters in length).

```
=IIF(LEN(Fields!myText.Value) < 100, Fields!myText.Value,
 IIF(LEN(Fields!myText.Value) < 200, Fields!myText.Value + "<br/><br/>",
 IIF(LEN(Fields!myText.Value) < 300, Fields!myText.Value + "<br/><br/><br/><br/>",
  Fields!myText.Value + "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>"))))))
```

Make sure the `CanGrow` and `CanShrink` properties are set according to your needs. (For the example above, `CanGrow` is set to True.

Comment: If you don't already have a placeholder in a cell, this page has the info on adding it - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/formatting-text-and-placeholders-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017 "Drag a field from the Report Data pane and drop it into the text box. ... The value of this placeholder will be the field expression that corresponds to the field that was dropped.
Right-click anywhere in the text box and select Insert Placeholder."

Answer (score 3):

From the Microsoft documentation [Change Row Height or Column Width (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/change-row-height-or-column-width-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017):

1. In Design view, click a cell in the table row.
2. In the Properties pane that displays, modify the Height property, and then click anywhere outside the Properties pane.

Changing the height of one cell appears to affect the whole row. It worked for me.