# SSRS. How to create new Row Group in right side of the table1_Details_Group?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, reporting-services, grouping

I'm creating Report with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

**PROBLEM:**
If I'm adding new `Row Group` It automatically adding before `table1_Details_Group`

**QUESTION:** How to change order of the groups or add new group in right side of the `table1_Details_Group`?

**EXPLAINATION:**

For now, after adding row group It looks like:

*Picture 1*

[image: Report SSRS For Now]

As you see in *picture 1* group is created in left side of `table1_Details_Group`

---

It **should be** like that:

*Picture 2*

[image: SSRS Report]

As you see in *Picture 2* is shown how I want to move `Column3` with grouped rows.

---

If impossible to make that is shown in *Picture 2*, have you ideas how to add all group with parent and all childs to right side of `table1_Details_Group` as shown in *Picture 3* below?

*Picture 3*

[image: SSRS Report]

Comment: You can manually add the column to the right side by clicking on column5 and then selecting the add column to right and then right click on the column cell and add the group manually

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I have tried It, but unsuccessfully. It's fine with creating column in right side, but when I try to add group on It (right click on new created column's cell > Add Group > Row Group > Parent Group) It automatically creating It in left side of the `table1_Details_Group`. If you see in `Picture 1` It adding after `Column3` and new created column stay empty. And new created column automatically is assigned to `table1_Details_Group`

Comment: (This is trick.)One more thing is just add the empty columns to the right side add the column value in cell you want to show group of and then just make the group columns visibility false.(I have not tried this so if dose not work then experiment with it as per your need. )

Comment: This is the link might be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933547/group-is-created-to-the-right-of-parent

Comment: I've tried in many ways, but nothing worked. I've tried to add columns in right side, added value to cell which I want to see, tried to delete group columns (only columns, without groups), but nothing helped. I can't make Visibility false in grouped columns.

Comment: I've tried the link you gave me, but this is not exactly I need. It's about how to create child in left side of parent.

Comment: @CoderofCode Thank you for trying to help, I've found solution by myself, posted It as answer, maybe It will be useful for someone :)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else coming here, you can insert a second detailed table *inside* a cell of the main table that has the detailed breakdown. This detailed table can be in any column without affecting the way rows are broken down in columns to the right or left.

So to solve the original question, first create Columns 1-3 in picture 1, and only include the data groupings required by those columns (ie. don't create the detailed row groupings for columns 4-5). Then insert the column where you want to show the detailed rows (ie between columns 2 and 3), and insert a *new* table ***inside*** that cell. This inner table will already be locked to share the same dataset as the main table. Then you can set the grouping of the inner rows and add whatever cells, rows or columns you need to the inner table. The columns to the right in the main table will still show the total, as in Picture 2.

Comment: This is the right solution! I tested it and it works.

Comment: then how about the column header? should it still include?

Comment: I made another table for the header

Answer (score 3):

I found solution, I don't know If It's good practice, but It worked for me.

I've created second table in right side, added similar group as in table1, and from new created table2 deleted all grouped columns, left only column which I needed, in this example `Column3`. So for now It looks like 1 table. `Column1` and  `Column2` from `Table1` are associated with `Column3` from `Table2`.

Comment: Yep, this works. I kept one "details" column at the end of the second table, so that I could set a fixed height on the details row of each table. Then I set CanGrow on all textboxes to false. I found another possible solution to dynamically grow row height, but I wasn't that ambitious:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386857/ssrs-setting-table-row-height

Comment: I cannot believe there is not a way to move the group to the right side of the Tablix. But this work-around gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can change layoutdirection of table from LTR to RTL.

go to tablix properties and collapse localization and then change layoutdirection

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same issue. The use of a second table was not perfect for me because when the report is viewed in HTML there is a space between the two tables, which looks weird (it worked fine in PDF view).

To resolve the issue, I created the table in picture 1 then removed all non-grouped columns (the table requires one visible column, so I had to keep a dummy column set to hidden).

Then I added new columns **inside** the grouping. In the cells for these columns I inserted another table. This inner table only has one cell with the value that I needed to display. The inner table then gets a filter so that it only displays values related to the current row of the parent table.

[image: Inner table filter]