# SSRS - How to make parent group to right side of child group

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

How to make parent group to right side of child group. Let's have below example.

```
ColumnA      | ColumnB          | ColumnC          | ColumnD          | ColumnE           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parent of All| Child of ColumnA | Child of ColumnB | Child of ColumnC | Child Of ColumnB  |
```

ColumnC and ColumnD are of same level but the values are different. So how to make ColumnE Parent group like ColumnC for ColumnD?

Comment: There's not an easy way but you can add a table inside the table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690237/ssrs-how-to-create-new-row-group-in-right-side-of-the-table1-details-group

Comment: I have already tried that and it causes formatting issue of columns like alignment of rows.